# How to solve the private browser problem after DNS change

Tags: javascript, laravel, http, dns

Hi I redirected my old domain name to the new one and it works but the problem is that when I launch the old domain name, there is a page that appears saying that my security is not private. Please help me.

Here is the message:
Your connection is not private.
Malicious individuals may attempt to steal your personal information from [www.yopougon.eatbu.com](http://www.yopougon.eatbu.com) (passwords, messages or credit card numbers, for example). Learn more about this
NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

Here is the domain to redirect: yopougongrill.com
Here is the new domain: yopougon.eatbu.com

[image]

Comment: You certificate in your remote machine linked to the domain `eatbu.com`, must have in his domains the subdomain `www.yopougon.eabu.com`.

Comment: Also it can be the browser cache because for me navigating to: https://yopougongrill.eatbu.com does not display a certificate error.

Comment: If this was in development then don't worry for new users it won't this error

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are not redirecting

`https://yopougongrill.com` -> `https://yopougon.eatbu.com`

You are redirecting

`https://yopougongrill.com` -> `https://www.yopougon.eatbu.com`

(which is not a valid subdomain for the certificate you are serving)

Answer (score 0):

Here are possible solutions

1. Refresh your browser.
2. Check your clock time. It could be because your pc time is not in sync with that of your browser. A possible solution is to allow your pc to set time automatically.
3. Clear your browser cache. But first, try loading the website in incognito mode.
4. Clearing your SSL state can help. If on windows, visit your internet options->content tab then clear cache.
5. update your DNS. if you have made changes to your DNS record in the past, you should set it to retrieve DNS automatically.